# Linux programming in C++

Tags: c++, linux

I've just finished reading Accelerated C++ so I'm still new to C++, but I want to learn Unix/Linux programming (as in command line applications and daemons). I've seen everyone recommending Advanced Programming in Unix Environment but it seems it's C-oriented. I know C++ is drawn from C so I can use every function in book in my C++ project, but for example - when it comes to opening a file: should I use open() from < fcntl.h> (as stated in book), or from < fstream>? Same goes with other functions in book. So, question is whether and when to use POSIX C functions when there are also "corresponding/matching" C++ functions.

Comment: Please use portable C++ whenever you can. Although you may run into some issues if you want to use advanced non-portable features not available in standard C++ like directories and sockets...

Comment: Please clarify "Unix/Linux" programming.  Do you want to do kernel programming?  Device Drivers?  Command line applications? GUI Applications?

Comment: The system calls are C functions so that book will work well. There are some abstractions for e.g. file and threads in the C++ standard library, but if you want to use other system calls (for example for networking) you have to resort to C function calls and structures. Also, there's some abstractions in the [Boost libraries](http://www.boost.org/), but if you in the future want to make portable code, you might want to consider cross-platform libraries like [Qt](http://qt-project.org/).

Comment: `Same goes with other chapters in book.` Remember - We don't have the book.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I'm not quite sure yet which way I'll go, but now I'm speaking of command line apps.

Comment: learn Unix/linux api's and how to use it. since almost all current Unix/linux systems are based on `C`, Operating System Specific interfaces uses `C` programming.

Comment: @JerryCoffin They don't really overlap.  You can't read an `int` using `read`, but you can't open a file with transactional integrity using `std::fstream`.  Depending on what you're doing, one or the other will make more sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Unix API is C (as is the Windows API); any calls into Unix will look
like C.  That doesn't stop you from using C++, however: if the function
requires a `char const*`, for example, you can call
`std::string::c_str()` on an `std::string`.

Whether you want the Unix function (e.g `read()`) or the C++ (`>>` on a
stream) depends on what you need.  The C++ functionality is generally at
a higher level; `read()` will only read an array of bytes, for example,
and will not parse integers in text format.  On the other hand, you
have a lot more low level control with `read()` and its assorted
functions; if you need transactional itegrity, for example, you'll need
to use `open()`, passing it the approriate flags, which aren't available
in `std::fstream::open()`.  More generally, the C++ functions that
involve interaction with the exterior (or with other threads) are built
on the underlying Unix system calls.  They provide a higher level of
abstraction, and will generally be simpler to use, but in specific
cases, they may not offer all of the functionality available at the lower levels.

Comment: So, I can easily use C++ functions, except in places where some low level control is needed? Would I have any trouble when using POSIX open() in code where I use some C++ API (e.g. NDB for MySQL Clusters)? Are there any performance differences in fstream::open() and POSIX open()?

Comment: @Bade Your first sentence sums it up perfectly.  In general, I would prefer the C++ library functions to the Posix interface, because they represent a higher level of abstraction (generally).  Mixing C++ and Posix functions is not a problem, but do be aware that if you use `open`, you cannot use any of the iostream functions on the returned fd, and if you use `std::fstream`, you can't use the Posix functions on that stream.er, since the C++ functions use the Posix functions as well.  But the

Comment: @Bade With regards to performance: the C++ library functions ultimately have to call the Posix functions as well, so calling Posix directly, if you don't need the added functionality of the C++ library, should be faster.  If you do need the added functionality, however, using Posix means you'll have to implement it yourself, and it's doubtful that you can do a better job that the experts who will have implemented the C++ library.  And for things like IO, the difference in performance is often negligible anyway.